# How to stop Apache HTTPS ReverseProxy passing basic auth to TomCat

Tags: centos, proxy, tomcat, authentication, apache-2.4

Apache currently interogates the user for their basic auth credentials, once the correct details are entered it passes basic auth credentials to the tomcat server it's proxying. This confuses the app which tried to use the basic auth creds as a login.

I would like to stop apache passing this information on.

I have configured apache using the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  app.company.co.uk
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Basic Auth"
            AuthUserFile /var/path/.htpasswd
            Require user user
            Satisfy any
            Deny from all
            Allow from 172.16.0.0/21
    </Location>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://app.company.co.uk:7190/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://app.company.co.uk:7190/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case in the past. Add `RequestHeader unset "Authorization"`.